# $_FILES uploads only 1 file

Tags: php

```
              <label class="labelFile">Bestand kiezen...</label>
                <input type="file" name="images_1" class="fileChoose" accept="image/*"></br></br></br>
                <label class="labelFile">Bestand kiezen...</label>
                <input type="file" name="images_2" class="fileChoose" accept="image/*"></br></br></br>
```

It only fills the first image and the second one it gives an errors: "4", how to fix it,
I want multiple input fields not 1 multiple :D

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put the form with

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

two items are returned to you
try like this

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES['images_1']);
var_dump($_FILES['images_2']);
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <label class="labelFile">Bestand kiezen...</label>
    <input type="file" name="images_1" class="fileChoose" accept="image/*"></br></br></br>
    <label class="labelFile">Bestand kiezen...</label>
    <input type="file" name="images_2" class="fileChoose" accept="image/*"></br></br></br>
    <button value="ppp" type="submit">send </button>
</form>
```